# DOMPDF @page :first selector is not working

Tags: dompdf

```
@page {
    margin: 20pt;
}
@page :first {
    margin-top: 0pt;
}
```

My first `@page` selector works fine at setting all page margins to 20pt. But the `@page :first` selector which should set the top margin to 0 on the first page only has absolutely no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug introduced in Dompdf 0.8.3. You can fall back to 0.8.2 or (when it's available) upgrade to the next release.

If you don't want to fall back to an earlier release you can grab a nightly download. There's a link in the [Dompdf project README](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: 0.8.4 version is asking for PHP 7.x which we can't upgrade now. Any workarounds to enable @page :first that used to work fine?

Comment: Besides rolling back to 0.8.2?